# UPS OAuth 2.0 RESTful API Integration

Tags: php, rest, curl, ups

I'm trying the integrate UPS's new RESTful API that uses OAuth 2.0 and this is the first time I'm doing this. Using the Client ID and Client Secret I'm able to get access token. And to get API services they have a documentation [here](https://developer.ups.com/api/reference). In almost all services they are requiring me to pass `transactionSrc` and `transId` as parameters in the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`, for example take this tracking request code example provided below ([source link from UPS](https://developer.ups.com/api/reference#operation/getSingleTrackResponseUsingGET)). Here they made these two parameters required and I have no idea what these two are. I did not find any detail on these two parameters anywhere.

So if anyone knows what these are or can redirect me to some resource that can give some light on this I would very much appreciate it.

```
/**
 * Requires libcurl
 */

const inquiryNumber = "YOUR_inquiryNumber_PARAMETER";
$query = array(
  "locale" => "en_US",
  "returnMilestones" => "false",
  "returnSignature" => "false"
);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR_TOKEN_HERE>",
    "UUID: string",
    "Username: string",
    "isCIE: string",
    "transId: string",
    "transactionSrc: string"
  ],
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://wwwcie.ups.com/api/trackservice/tracking/v1/details/" . inquiryNumber . "?" . http_build_query($query),
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$error = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($error) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $error;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: I found some old legacy documentation from UPS where they vaguely describes these two parameters. And basically transactionSrc is the source application name from where the API is being called and transID is some unique identifier that will help to identify the API request so basically giving the API request an ID. Here is the link if any one is interested. https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit/downloadresource?loc=en_US

Answer (score 0, accepted):

transId is just a unique Transaction ID that you provide so you can identify a specific request made "An identifier unique to the request. Length 32".  Personally I am just generating a guid for this.  transactionSrc just the source of this transaction "An identifier of the client/source application that is making the request.Length 512".

Comment: this is just a comment and the answer. please provide code or supporting information

Comment: I found some legacy documentation where they described these parameters a little. I came back here to add the information I found from the documentation and what @Brad said is true.